# Limit of CDF of increasing sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable and $a_1<a_2<...<a_n$ is an increasing sequence with $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = a$. Is it true that $Probability(X\leq a) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} Probability(X\leq a_n)$? It seems intuitively true but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

What would happen if $P(X=a) \ne 0$?

Comment: I don't really follow, could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Ok... let $a_n = 1-1/n$ and $X$ be Bernoulli distributed, i.e. $P(X=0) = P(X=1) = 1/2.$

Comment: In this case, $a = 1$, so $Prob(X\leq 1) = 1$, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} Prob(X\leq a_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{x=0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}} P(x)$, I'm not sure where to go from there

Comment: What does $\sum_{x=0}^{1-1/n}$ even mean? Let's do it for $a_2 = 1/2.$ $P(X\le a_2) = P(X\le 1/2).$ What is that? Now for $a_3.$ What is $P(X\le 2/3)?$ See how this is gonna go?

Comment: Is the point that it is never going to reach $P(X=1)$ so it is always going to be $\frac{1}{2}$ and not $1$?

Comment: yep, that is the point